# How to get the tag's name and its id when mouse's focus is on it?

Tags: javascript, events, focus

I want a  function  to show tag's name and id when focus is in the tag.
For example,
focus is on input whose id is `1th`,show `input` and `1th` with console.log.
focus is on textarea whose id is `2th`,show `textarea` and `2th` with console.log.

```
ob = window.document.getElementsByTag("");
function getNameAndId(event){
    console.log(tag's name and id);
}
ob.addEventListener("focus",getNameAndId);
```

```html
 
content:<input id="1th" type="text">
<br/>
content:<textarea id="2th" cols=6 rows=5></textarea>
<br/>
content:<input id="3th" type="text">
<br/>
content:<input id="4th" type="text">
```

In my demo,i don't know how to define `ob`

```
ob = window.document.getElementsByTag("");
```

How to show tag's name and id when focus is in it?

```
console.log(tag's name and id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegation here. Assign the event listener to an parent element (for example the `body`) while using capture (indicated by the `true` passed in as third parameter to `addEventListener`). Then use `event.target` to get the element:

```js
function getNameAndId(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    console.log("Tag: " + target.tagName);
    console.log("Id: " + target.id);
}
document.body.addEventListener("focus", getNameAndId, true);
```

```html
 
content:<input id="1th" type="text">
<br/>
content:<textarea id="2th" cols=6 rows=5></textarea>
<br/>
content:<input id="3th" type="text">
<br/>
content:<input id="4th" type="text">
```

**Note:** This will capture the focus event on all focusable elements inside the `body`. You can narrow that by either specifying another close parent than `body` or by checking the `tagName` to only accept specific element types.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can find active element id.

```
var activeElementId = document.activeElement.id;
```

Then, you can get tag name like this code.

```
var ob = document.getElementById(activeElementId).tagName;
```

Finally

```
console.log("tag's name: " + ob + ", activeElementId: " + activeElementId);
```

Comment: Why use `document.getElementById(activeElementId).tagName;` to get the tag name. You can simply use: `document.activeElement.tagName`.

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to wrap this into a more scalable wrapper..

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
            window.addEventListener("focusin", (event)=> {
                if (event && event.target) {
                    console.log(`ID = ${event.target.getAttribute("id")}`);
                    console.log(`NAME = ${event.target.tagName}`);
                }
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="hello" style="border: 1px solid #000; padding: 20px;">
</body>
```